# Short story about two people who ran for their lives

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I can't remember many details about the story. I think I read it in a collection. It had something to do with two people who were of a race of people with a lifespan of 6 (?) days (don't remember precise number of days, but I remember they aged very, very quickly). They ran and somehow were able to drastically outlive their lifespan? They got to some abandoned ship at the very end.

Comment: I think I remember this story. Its very old. 1970s or earlier. The one I am thinking of, they are running trying to reach the ship, (possibly running during sunrise or sunset, to hot during day to cold at night) Many people try to make it to the ship, but either die or turn back) Finally a young couple make it to the ship, and fall down paralyzed once they enter. After 2-3 days unable to move and only watching the passage of the sun through a porthole, the man turns his head and he can sees his girl has not aged. Shortly they can move and then use the tech from the ship to help everyone.

Comment: This is Bradbury's ["Frost and Fire"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_and_Fire_(short_story)) (1946).

Comment: @DavidW Yes that is the story I described. Pretty sure its the one the OP is asking about.

Comment: There was a comment from the OP confirming DavidW's response is correct, but they later deleted it. (cc @TheLethalCarrot)

Comment: Ah sorry, I deleted my comment because I asked DavidW to post an answer to the question and then the question got closed, not realizing I deleted my confirmation of the answer! "Frost and Fire" is correct, thank you so much!

Comment: @Otis Ah, sorry. I just re-closed against the target that John Rennie used originally, without checking it, assuming the only reason it had been reopened was that the confirmation comment *here* was gone.